# How can I change my font weight to medium in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Why is the .medium system font not showing for .title style in SwiftUI?

I have also tried explicitly setting the font with Font.custom...

```swift
Text("Text").font(Font.title.weight(.light))
                    
Text("Text").font(Font.title.weight(.regular))
                    
Text("Text").font(Font.title.weight(.medium))
                    
Text("Text").font(Font.title.weight(.semibold))
                    
Text("Text").font(Font.title.weight(.bold))
```

Here is my output:

I am expecting .medium to be heavier than .regular.

[image]

Answer (score 31):

The best way to achieve this is by splitting up the font type and the font weight into two separate parts.

```swift
Text("Text")
    .font(.title)
    .fontWeight(.medium)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It does help, but I still have the problem of not being able to see the medium font weight.

Comment: This may be due to how your are setting up your SwiftUI code, if you send me the full project then I may be able to help

Comment: @GavinJensen I had similar issue when I was using custom font and that was due the family font name needs to change accordingly to the weight.

Comment: What about for Views that are not Text?

Comment: Is fontWeight deprecated? I'm getting an error that the method doesn't exist.

Comment: No fontWeight is not deprecated. Here is the documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/fontweight(_:)

Comment: I got the error too about it not existing, which turned out to be because I had modifiers in this order: `Text("Text").padding().font(.title).fontWeight(.medium)`. When I switched the order to `Text("Text").font(.title).fontWeight(.medium).padding()` it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Text("Home")
    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
```

> > Use like this